# Created Index in MongoDB but the error comes everytime: unable to find index for $geoNear query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to fetch the data(nearby locations) from the nodejs file in mongodb. I have created an index in mongodb but when I query for it, I get this error:

```
{ name: 'MongoError', 
message: 'Unable to execute query: error processing query:
ns=event_management.locations limit=1000 skip=0\nTree: GEONEAR
field=loc maxdist=500000 isNearSphere=0\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n planned
returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query',
'$err':Unable to execute query: error processing
query:ns=event_management.locations limit=1000 skip=0\nTree: GEONEAR  
field=loc maxdist=500000 isNearSphere=0\nSort: {}\nProj: {}\n planner 
returned error: unable to find index for $geoNear query',
code: 17007 }
```

Query I'm using to fetch the data from node is:

```
domain.Location.find(
{
  loc:{
    $near :{$geometry:{type:"Point",coordinates: [parseFloat(longitude), parseFloat(latitude) ] },
    $maxDistance: parseFloat(distance)*1000}
  }
}
```

and the command using for creating index is:

```
db.locations.ensureIndex({ loc: "2dsphere"});
```

I can't figure out that where I'm wrong. Please help me with this if anyone can.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How you are storing lat and lng in you DB??

Comment: loc : {
       type: {
         type: String,
         required: true,
         enum: ['Point', 'LineString', 'Polygon'],
         default: 'Point'
       },
       coordinates: []
    }
The lat and long are stored in string format. The above code is the model defined in node

Answer (score 0):

According to me there is an error related to distance ($maxDistance). You are exceeding the limit. And hence none of Index with that condition could be found. I'm just lightly in confidence about it.

```
domain.Location.find(
{
  loc:{
    $near :{$geometry:{type:"Point",coordinates: [parseFloat(longitude), parseFloat(latitude) ] },
    $maxDistance: parseFloat(distance)}
  }
}
```